# CSS white-space nowrap parent, wrap child

Tags: css

I'm making some digital lesson plans and I am in need of some help. I am trying to make each `<section>` sit next to each other in an inline-block style. Since each section is 500px wide, any extra sections that do not fit in the viewport should be able to be scrolled to horizontally.

**What I need:** Essentially, everything on the page should stay fixed in place except the five `section` elements, and the possibility that the interior of a section might be taller than visible. I want the teachers to be able to horizontally scroll to see days of the week that are out of range of the monitor's viewport.

**How I tried to fix:** I was able to get the sections to sit next to each other with horizontal scroll whenever I used the `white-space: nowrap` property, however, this causes the text inside of the section to leave the section, which is not desirable. Text should be contained inside the 500px width, I just need the sections to line up next to each other in one single row.

If there is another approach I should take, I am open to changing the CSS formatting. I'm still learning, so any explanations would be super helpful so I can learn and grow.

Raw pastern: https://pastebin.com/xX8LjyNq

```css
  body {margin: 0;}

  .centered {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;}

  nav {
    z-index: 3;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0; left: 0;
    width: 100%; height: 65px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray}

  #title {
    z-index: 2;
    position: fixed;
    top: 65px; left: 0;
    width: 100%; height: 80px;
    font-size: 36px;
    color: #484848;
    background-color: white;
    border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray}


  /* --------[LESSON PLAN]-------- */
  #lessonPlan {
    position: absolute;
    top: 146px; left: 0;
    max-width: 2600px;
    overflow-x: scroll;}

  #lessonPlan section {
    width: 500px;
    min-height: calc(100vh - 205px);
    margin: 0;
    padding: 16px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-right: 1px solid lightgray}

  .weekday {
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    font-weight: 800;
    font-size: 26px;
    color: #484848;
    text-align: center;}

  .alignment .title, .objective .title, .materials .title, .assignments .title{
    color: #484848;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-decoration: underline;}

  #container ul {
      padding: 0px 30px;
      list-style: none;}
  #container li {
    padding: 10px 8px;
    margin-bottom: 6px;
    border: 1px solid white}
  #container li:hover {
    border-radius: 20px;
    border: 1px solid lightgray;}
  #container li a {
    font-weight: 800;
    text-decoration: none;}

  /* --------[BOTTOMBAR]-------- */
  #bottombar {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px; left: 0;
    width: 100%; height: 60px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 100vw;
    padding: 0px 10px;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    border-top: 1px solid lightgray}

  #bottombar .controls span {
    margin-right: 10px;
    color: #484848;}

  #bottombar select{
    appearance: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    font-size: 18px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    border: 1px solid gray}

  #bottombar input {
    padding: 6px 16px;
    font-size: 18px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    border: 1px solid gray}

  #bottombar .button { /* <- Customizes the global button design */
    padding: 8px 24px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    font-size: 18px;
    border-radius: 26px}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../resources/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Indie+Flower">
    <title>5th Grade Team | Weekly Lesson Plans</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <nav></nav>

    <div id='title' class='centered'> <span>Week 2</span> </div>
    <div id='lessonPlan'>
      <div id='container'>
        <section>
              <div class='weekday'>Mon, Aug 23rd</div>
              <div class='alignment'>
                <span class='title'>Standards:</span>
                <ul><li class='standard'><span class='oas'>(1.R.3)</span> I can work with others to discuss topics and texts.</li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <div class='objective'>
                <span class='title'>Objective:</span>
                <ul><li>1. Students will complete the Buckle Down assessment. </li><li>2. Students will learn about agricultural practices. </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <div class='materials'>
                <span class='title'>Materials:</span>
                <ul><li>Complete Buckle Down Assessment</li><li>Plant Tobacco </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </section><section>
              <div class='weekday'>Tue, Aug 24th</div>
              <div class='alignment'>
                <span class='title'>Standards:</span>
                <ul><li class='standard'><span class='oas'>(SS.1.1)</span> I can summarize the reasons settlers came to the Americas.</li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <div class='objective'>
                <span class='title'>Objective:</span>
                <ul><li>1. Students will look through the Jamestown Fort Project and begin to make a plan.</li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <div class='materials'>
                <span class='title'>Materials:</span>
                <ul><li><a target='_blank' href='https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gv-uFx_H7GoE86GQ2KQrcuv0FOIJNNNk/view?usp=sharing'> Susan Constant</a></li><li><a target='_blank' href='https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MuXSxHtJgOhFM4bb6QT3cfArcH5Uae4s/view?usp=sharing'> Jamestown Anticipation</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </section><section>
              <div class='weekday'>Wed, Aug 25th</div>
              <div class='alignment'>
                <span class='title'>Standards:</span>
                <ul><li class='standard'><span class='oas'>(SS.1.2)</span> I can explain the economic/political reasons for establishing Jamestown.</li><li class='standard'><span class='oas'>(6.R.1)</span> I can create research questions to find information.</li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <div class='objective'>
                <span class='title'>Objective:</span>
                <ul><li>1. Students will examine primary sources and draw conclusions from what they find. </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <div class='materials'>
                <span class='title'>Materials:</span>
                <ul><li><a target='_blank' href='https://www.nps.gov/jame/learn/historyculture/the-first-residents-of-jamestown.htm'> Jamestown Residents </a></li><li>Gentlemen POV Writing Activity</li><li><a target='_blank' href='https://youtu.be/y6AZac_u8Sk?t=89'> Virginia Colony Pt. 1</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </section><section>
              <div class='weekday'>Thu, Aug 26th</div>
              <div class='alignment'>
                <span class='title'>Standards:</span>
                <ul><li class='standard'><span class='oas'>(SS.1.4)</span> I can explain the successes and challenges that happened at Jamestown. </li><li class='standard'><span class='oas'>(2.R.2)</span> I can determine the genre of what I am reading. </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <div class='objective'>
                <span class='title'>Objective:</span>
                <ul><li>1. Students will identify elements of a biography. </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <div class='materials'>
                <span class='title'>Materials:</span>
                <ul><li><a target='_blank' href='https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dAYXTwYR9RtPpBbKx9kV-1w9br_L5Dae/view?usp=sharing'> Biography of John Smith</a></li><li><a target='_blank' href='https://youtu.be/y6AZac_u8Sk?t=237'> Virginia Colony Pt. 2</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </section><section>
              <div class='weekday'>Fri, Aug 27th</div>
              <div class='alignment'>
                <span class='title'>Standards:</span>
                <ul><li class='standard'><span class='oas'>(SS.1.1)</span> I can summarize the reasons settlers came to the Americas.</li><li class='standard'><span class='oas'>(2.R.1)</span> I can summarize what I have read.</li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <div class='objective'>
                <span class='title'>Objective:</span>
                <ul><li>1. Students can summarize information from a text on their own.</li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <div class='materials'>
                <span class='title'>Materials:</span>
                <ul><li>Powhatan Trade Sort</li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </section>      </div>
    </div>

    <form id='bottombar' method='get'>
      <div class='controls'>
        <span>Teacher:</span>
        <select name='utid'>
          
          <option value='1' >Mr. Teacher</option>
          <option value='2'  disabled>Mrs. Teacher</option>
          <option value='3'  disabled>Mrs. Teacher</option>
          <option value='4'  disabled>Ms. Teacher</option>
                  </select>
        <select name='week'>
          <option value='2' >Week 2</option><option value='1' selected>Week 1</option><option value='0' >Week 0</option>        </select>
        <button class='button purple-btn'>Go</button>
      </div>
      <button class='button purple-btn' type='button' onclick='location.href="csv.php?utid=1&week=2";'>Download</button>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It can be done pretty trivially with flexbox, grid, or table layout. I suggest you investigate flexbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#container {
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;}
```

Add this to your style.